# Enterprise Architect custom hotkey for Addin

Tags: custom-controls, add-in, enterprise-architect, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I am currently working on an Enterprise Architect addin, and i really need to use some custom hotkeys for user preference. It is working correctly by using functionality from this article: https://community.sparxsystems.com/community-resources/805-triggering-add-in-functionality-with-custom-hotkeys-in-enterprise-architect , but with this way of using custom hotkeys Enterprise Architect is constantly using one core of the processor massively -> if i remove the addin dll, and delete the key from the registry this problem disappears, and i am sure now that the custom hotkey functionality causes it.

Can anyone help me by offering another way of using custom hotkeys in an enterprise architect addin? Searching for another solution for a long time now, but haven't achieved any progress in it yet.

Tamas

EDIT... FOUND THE SOLUTION: modify InvisibleHotKeyForm.cs and Hotkey.cs

InvisibleHotKeyForm.cs modification:
delete "worker_DoWork" method and

```
public partial class InvisibleHotKeyForm : Form
{
    private const double Button_MilliSec = 10.0;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Hotkey> _hotkeys;
    private readonly int _thisProcessId;
    private int _lastActiveProcessId;
    private readonly BackgroundWorker _worker;
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer_Button;

public InvisibleHotKeyForm(IEnumerable<Hotkey> hotkeys)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._thisProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    this._worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.Timer_Init(10.0);
    this._hotkeys = hotkeys;
    this._lastActiveProcessId = this._thisProcessId;
    Closing += (sender, eventArgs) => ((List<Hotkey>)_hotkeys).ForEach(key => key.Dispose());
}

private void Timer_Init(double Millisec)
{
    this.Timer_Button = new System.Timers.Timer();
    this.Timer_Button.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    this.Timer_Button.Interval = Millisec;
    this.Timer_Button.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int id = ActiveProcess.GetActiveProcess().Id;
    if (this._lastActiveProcessId == id)
        return;
    if (this._thisProcessId == id)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Delegate)new MethodInvoker(RegisterHotKeys));
    }
    else if (this._thisProcessId != id)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Delegate)new MethodInvoker(UnregisterHotKeys));
    }
    this._lastActiveProcessId = id;
}
```

.
.
.

and Hotkey.cs modification:

```
public class Hotkey : IDisposable
{
    public const int WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID = 786;
    private Keys Key { get; set; }
    private Modifiers Modifiers { get; set; }
    public HotkeyHandler Handler { get; private set; }
    private int Id { get; set; }

private IWin32Window _registeredWindow;
private bool _registered;

public Hotkey(Keys key, Modifiers modifiers, HotkeyHandler handler)
{
    this._registeredWindow = (IWin32Window)null;
    this._registered = false;
    this.Key = key;
    this.Modifiers = modifiers;
    this.Handler = handler;
    Id = GetHashCode();
}
```

.
.
.

Comment: If it were still 2003 I'd say: tell Sparx to implement a new feature and see it the next month. But it's 2017 and this has been requested since many years. Well, most likely you have to use better hardware as long as you have to deal with Windoze - and EA.

Comment: +1 Good-To-Know thing: a colleague of mine could solve this problem, but that won't help me out, because he cannot find the source code, nor he remembers how he did it, i only have the .dll file to work with...

Comment: Tamas, this is a question/answer site, so if you found the answer you can post it here, even on your own question. That way, in 5 years time, people will still be able to find the answer (after you have moved on to newer things)